# Unity3d: How can i set to null cursor in window class using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, unity-game-engine

I want make system cursor suport in my game with Unity3d. But there is no support of system cursor change in Unity. 
Using this code

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern System.IntPtr LoadCursor(System.IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern System.IntPtr SetCursor(System.IntPtr hCursor);
```

I can change cursor, but OS changing it after me. I tried doin this in each frame, but it seems like OS still changing it with other frequency. I think it's because of different FPS in game and OS or somethig.

I found this on MSDN:

> If your application must set the cursor while it is in a window, make
>   sure the class cursor for the specified window's class is set to NULL.
>   If the class cursor is not NULL, the system restores the class cursor
>   each time the mouse is moved.

So I want set the class cursor for my window class to NULL, but i can't find out how.

Comment: ...er I think it does support hardware cursors: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/10/22/cursor-api/?

Comment: Unity's CursorAPI can't do it, because it's for only one cursor and don't let you change it to othe system pointers(hand, arrows etc.).